# ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'C:\code\myproj\content\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\vendor'

Tags: gulp, visual-studio-2017, gulp-sass

Updated Visual Studio and now getting Error message when try and build project:

`ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'C:\code\myproj\content\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\vendor'`

In package.json I have : `"gulp-sass": "^3.1.0",`

I have checked path and sure enough no `vendor` folder? But how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to rebuild packages then in Visual Studio went to `Tools -> options -> Projects and Solutions -> Web Package Management`

I had to move `.\node_modules\.bin` to top of list in `Location of External Tools:` section.

Answer (score 5):

A few things you could try are rebuilding `node-sass`

```
npm rebuild node-sass
```

Or simply reinstalling your package

```
npm i
```

If neither of those work, I would try deleting your `node_modules` directory, and then `npm i` again.